# In Unity C#, How to send a player (rolling ball) to starting point on impact with a lower plane?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a rolling ball on a plane and I have a hole in the plane. There is a lower plane I put under the original plane. I want to set it so that the player "ball" will go back to the start if it hits that lower plane.

I'm very new. I'm thinking about using a collision method or maybe trigger on impact or something, but have a lack of knowledge of how to go about doing this. Any tips?

Comment: If I remember well, the tutorial has a part where when you fall from the path, you restart at the beginning, may b you should read the entire tutorial before adding new features?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then come back and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way. I made it so that if the vertical position of the ball fell below the playing field, it would set the game object back to the starting position, which I can set as the position of the player on the first frame.

Answer (score 0):

You could store a "Starting Position" as a `Vector3` and set the position of the ball to this position if it collides with the lower plane using Unity's `OnCollisionEnter` method.

```
// The position of the ball will be stored here.
public Vector3 ballPosition;

// Where the ball should start/go back to if it falls.
public Vector3 startPosition;

void Start() {
    ballPosition = ball.tranform.position;  // Assign the ball position here.
    startPosition = new Vector3(x, y, z);  // Replace x, y, z with your start co-ordinates.
}

// If the ball collides with the lower plane, position it at the Start Position.
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
   ballPosition = startPosition;
}
```

Put this code in a script and put that onto your lower plane. Then, when anything collides with that plane, the ball will be transported to the start position.